# How can you find the index of a list within a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I know for 1d arrays there is a function called np.in1d that allows you to find the indices of an array that are present in another array, for example:

```
a = [0,0,0,24210,0,0,0,0,0,21220,0,0,0,0,0,24410]
b = [24210,24610,24410]

np.in1d(a,b)

yields [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]
```

I was wondering if there was a command like this for finding lists in a list of lists?

```
c = [[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]
d = [[0,0,1],[1,0,1]]

something like np.in2d(c,d)

would yield [True, True, False,  True, False]
```

Edit:  I should add, I tried this with in1d and it flattens the 2d lists so it does not give the correct output.

```
I did np.in1d(c,d) and the result was [ True,  True,  True,  
True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  
True]
```

Comment: Since you just want the indexes of the outer list, `in1d` should work.

Comment: Not a command but ```[x in b for x in a]``` works. You just have to switch variables so that _a_ is the larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
[x in d for x in c]
```

Comment: This is not fully correct, you need to maintain _c_ as the larger of the arrays for this to work.